# what is the relationship of babel polyfill and runtime?

Tags: babeljs

> Babel includes a polyfill that includes a custom regenerator runtime
>   and core-js.
>
> Another purpose of this transformer is to create a sandboxed
>   environment for your code. If you use babel-polyfill and the built-ins
>   it provides such as Promise, Set and Map

According to the documentation,I have think about these information and get the follow points:

1. polyfill is included in babel,so if we use babel-loader,polyfill will be automatically contained in the transpiled result.
2. babel-plugin-transform-runtime will only alias the name of the important classes,itself does not contain any polyfill or runtime.
3. if you don't use babel-plugin-transform-runtime,the polifill will also be contained in the transpiled result,but without being aliased.

Am I right?

Comment: You can check every of those items yourself.

Answer (score 0):

babel-polyfill is not included when you use babel-loader:
  babel-loader's role is to tell webpack how to transform the source files.
  If you want to use babel-polyfill:
    first, install it by running `npm install --save babel-polyfill`
    second, require or import it in the top of your entry file `import 'babel-polyfill'`

babel-plugin-transform-runtime should be used only when developing a library because babel-polyfill modifies the globals: for example when you use babel-polyfill the global window.Object will contain properties like `assign`, and new APIs like Promise, Set, Map will be available as globals if your browser does not support them, otherwise you should use the babel-polyfill.

Comment: I can't understand what means `otherwise you should use the babel-polyfill`.
Isn't it `otherwise you should use the babel-plugin-transform-runtime `?

Comment: this means if you are not writing a library you should use `babe-polyfill`